# How do you translate mouse coordinates into "mm"

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to convert the distance from a mouse press to mouse release into mm. I already calculated the distance but am not sure how to convert to the correct units.

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        xAtPress = event->x();
        yAtPress = event->y();
        qDebug() << "Mouse X press: " << xAtPress;
        qDebug() << "Mouse Y press: " << yAtPress;
    }
}
void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) 
    {
        int xAtRelease = event->x();
        int yAtRelease = event->y();
        qDebug() << "Mouse X release: " << xAtRelease;
        qDebug() << "Mouse Y release: " << yAtRelease;
        int dx = xAtRelease - xAtPress;
        int dy = yAtRelease - yAtPress;
        qDebug() << "Dx: " << dx;
        qDebug() << "Dy: " << dy;


        //Create some kind of conversion function here.


    }
}
```

Comment: To calculate a distance in mm space from pixel space you'll need some monitor calibration information. You need to know the resolution (in pixels) as well as the size of each pixel (both with and height). Some monitors provider DPI information (and more), some don't (in which case you'll have to ask the user to manually calibrate the display and provide values). Scaling, as applied in some cases by some modern OS's, provide even further complications. I work with medical imaging an this is a *huge* pain in the neck. By no means a trivial problem.

Comment: Not to mention that not all vendors DPI etc information is actually correct / reliable. That's partly why certified "diagnostic grade" monitors exist (that cost a fortune).

Comment: @JesperJuhl If the physical size of the screen is known, wouldn't it then be possible to simply do _physical x/y size divided by number of x/y pixels_? (Then you'd have pixels per x/y mm or inch or whatnot)

Comment: @nada More or less. How accurate do you need to be? "Somewhat accurate, it's a game"?, "Quite accurate, I'm building physical things based on the numbers"? Or "critically important, must be exact, I'm doing medical diagnosis and people's lives depend on the accuracy"?

Comment: There's also pixel spacing to take into account if we are in the "accuracy is critical" area.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I bet there are specialized screens with precise pixel per mm or whatever for those precision critical use cases.

Comment: Well, OP, if you're trying to bring people to mars, better contact your goverment's space agency - for most other use cases use the formula above.

Comment: I love it when someone points out, "My phone does X in a couple seconds..." And then I have to explain "The phone isn't keeping planes in the air."

Comment: @nada there are. And they easily cost $15000+ . I'm just asking to get an idea of what your need is. You haven't told us what domain you work in nor what problem you are trying to solve (for what purpose), so we have no idea what your accuracy needs are, and hence, how complete/complicated a solution you need.

Comment: If you are just doing a game or some non-critical business application, then calculating a distance in mm based on your screens EDID information is probably "good enough" - although you probably also want to make sure to take OS display scaling into account.

Comment: I am trying to get quite accurate, I'm building physical things based on the numbers... This seems very complicated right now. @JesperJuhl

Comment: @JesperJuhl is there any other resources you know of that I can use to get a better insight on this.

Comment: @testStackFlow "This seems very complicated right now" - Well, that's because it *is* rather complicated. Step one is to get the EDID information from your monitor so you know how big the screen is, how big pixels are and what resolution the display is running at. Then you need to query the OS for its scaling and take that into account. Then you have your actual pixel coordinates that you then have to translate. And if the monitor and OS info you got was all correct (it's not always) then you can calculate a mm space number.

Comment: _I'm building physical things based on the numbers..._ Sorry, stupid question: Isn't it usual in construction drawings anymore to draw little arrows with numbers for measures? (I saw this when I visited the engineers in my company.) Or am I thinking too old-fashioned once again?

Comment: @Scheff Absolutely yes!  And there will be a warning printed somewhere "Do not scale".

Answer (score 2):

**In short:**
You can't (at least not accurately and reliably).

**In long:**
In order to perform even the most basic conversion you need to know the conversion factor between pixels and mm. And in order to calculate this factor you need to know the resolution of the screen (e.g. via [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html)) and the **real** size of the screen - which is is the problematic part. `QScreen` even provides a `physicalSize()` function which returns the size of the screen (in mm) - but then warns

> Depending on what information the underlying system provides the value might not be entirely accurate.

which essentially means: In the **best case** your monitor correctly provides that information and your OS correctly handles that information so you will get sensible data; **more likely** you will get utter nonsense; **worst case** you get values that look plausible - but actually are subtly incorrect.

In essence there is **no reliable way** to query that information from the OS, so you can't do it.